# ionic 2 and Facebook login, back to my page and it's blank

Tags: javascript, facebook, ionic2

Using ionic 2 and Facebook plugin recommended by ionic 2, when I login using Facebook, I am redirected to facebook and I have to authorized the app. Then I go back to my app BUT in **landscape mode only** my current page is white (blank)... I just do nothing more than facebook login...

If I am on the blank page and I switch my phone to portrait then again to landscape, the page appear, so weiiirrrd!

Somebody knows what?